# What's the meaning of homomorphism preserving the gradings here?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the sentence labeled by red line, what's the meaning of homomorphism preserving the gradings here?
[image: Fu84]
[image: Fu85]
[image: Fu86]
[image: Fu87]

Comment: Why are you posting 4 pages when your question is about a sentence in the first page ?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $S$ and $T$ are graded means that we have decompositions $S=\bigoplus S_d$ and $T= \bigoplus T_d$, and the fact that $\phi: S\to T$ preserves the grading means that $\phi(S_d)\subset T_d$ for any $d$.